# MySQLでのNOT EXISTSを置き換えて高速化方法で試行錯誤中

Tags: mysql, sql

数日試行錯誤しており、
解決できない為、ご質問方法も初心者で内容も初歩的でここでのご質問は失礼かとも思いましたが、
解決へのご指導いただきたく、投稿させて頂きますことをお許し頂ければと思います。

■問題点
果物での例ですが、
MySQLで、
・company_idで指定したお客様会社で、
・果物ごとに購入日buy_dateが、
・本日以降がないデータが、抽出対象
・昨日以前のデータで、且、最大日のデータを抽出
・最大日のレコードが複数該当した場合は全て抽出
のレコードを抽出したいのです。

NOT EXISTSを使用し正常に該当レコードを抽出できていたのですが、
レコード件数が、約9万件になった現在約20秒の抽出時間がかかるようになってしまいました。

そこで、試行錯誤していたのですが、
ネットで、NOT EXISTSをLEFT JOINに置き換えて高速化という開発アドバイスのページを見つけ、
SQL文を組みなおしたのですが、SQL文の文法エラーになります。

⇒ SQL実行エラー#1109.データベースメッセージ
"Unknown table 'f1' in where clause"

f1のスコープが、SQL文の中まで有効でない為にでていると考えていますが、
回避策を調べても、試行錯誤しても、解決できずに困っています。
どのような記述方法にすれば、このSQLの抽出を実現できるSQL文にできますでしょうか？

▼food テーブル構造

```
CREATE TABLE `food` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `food_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `buy_date` date default NULL,
  `food_name` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `company_id` (`company_id`),
  KEY `food_id` (`food_id`),
  KEY `buy_date` (`buy_date`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

▼food テーブルデータ例

```
int        int     verchar(255)  date        int       ・・・
AutoIndent key                   key         key       ・・・
主キー   
---------------------------------------------------------------
 id      food_id   food_name     buy_date    company_id・・・
---------------------------------------------------------------
  1        1       みかん        2018-03-01  100       ・・・
  2        1       みかん        2018-03-01  200       ・・・   ★抽出対象
  3        2       りんご        2018-03-05  200       ・・・
  4        3       ばなな        2018-02-23  200       ・・・   ★抽出対象
  5        2       りんご        2018-03-10  200       ・・・   ★抽出対象
  6        5       なし          2017-12-31  200       ・・・
  7        2       りんご        2018-03-19  100       ・・・
  8        4       まんごー      2018-05-30  200       ・・・   ※本日以降
  9        5       なし          2018-03-20  200       ・・・   ※本日以降
  ：       ：        ：             ：        ：         ：
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

上記テーブルから、
id=2,4,5を抽出したいです。

▼ネットに『NOT EXISTSが遅いのを高速化する方法』として見つけた記述方法。

```
01   SELECT *
02   FROM
03     food AS f1
04   LEFT JOIN (
05     SELECT 
06       DISTINCT f2.food_id
07     FROM
08       food AS f2
09     WHERE
10           (f2.company_id = 200)
11       AND (f1.company_id = 200)
12       AND (f1.food_id    = f2.food_id)
13       AND (f1.buy_date   < f2.buy_date)
14   ) LOG_TEMP
15   ON
16     LOG_TEMP.food_id = f1.food_id
17   WHERE
18     LOG_TEMP.food_id is null;
```

▼現在、使用しているがレコード数が増え、著しく処理が遅くなってきたSQL文。

・テーブル内全レコード数：約9万件
・抽出されるレコード数：812件
・処理時間：約18～22秒

```
  SELECT *
  FROM
    food AS f1
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM
        food AS f2
      WHERE
            (f2.company_id = 200)
        AND (f1.company_id = 200)
        AND (f1.food_id    = f2.food_id)
        AND (f1.buy_date   < f2.buy_date)
    )
```

以上です。

---

▼本件の結果のご報告 (2018/03/22 以下追記)

問題解決した最終SQL文。
・処理速度：約20秒 → 約0.15秒
・確認時の抽出レコード：781件（件数は運用中サーバーの為、刻々と変化）
・抽出レコード内容：改善前と同一内容・件数
・結果：改善成功！！
・最終のSQL文

```
SELECT f2.*
FROM
  (
  SELECT food_id, MAX(buy_date) AS max_buy_date
  FROM
    food
  WHERE
    company_id = 200
  GROUP BY food_id
  ) AS f1
INNER JOIN food AS f2
ON
      (f1.food_id      = f2.food_id)
  AND (f1.max_buy_date = f2.buy_date)
WHERE
  (f2.company_id = 200)
```

ごたごたのご質問でしたが、
適切なご指摘やSQL文のご提示をありがとうございました。
大変お手数やお心遣いありがとうございました。

Comment: 参照したページはこちらですかね？　http://kkoudev.github.io/blog/2013/09/14/sql/

Comment: 質問されることについては全く問題ありません。ただし質問内容について確認したい点があります。`food_id`が主キーということでしょうか。`food_id=2`が抽出され`food_id=1`が抽出されない理由を説明していただけますでしょうか。また質問されている抽出条件とSQL文が全く別物で、どちらについて尋ねているのか判断できません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。参照したページはそちらです。テーブルデータ見本の１列目に、主キーのid列（Auto Indent)を追加しました。「food_id=1が抽出され」は記述ミスです。申し訳ございません。主キーのidの2,4,5を抽出したいです。理由は、「food_idの中で、buy_dateが最大の過去のレコードを全て抽出」したい為です。

Comment: テーブル名 bood はtypoかなと。

Comment: foodへ修正しました。ここへの誤記です。ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: テーブル構造が間違っていたんですね。SQL文では`company_id`が扱われていますが抽出条件では触れられていません。どちらが正しいのでしょうか？

Comment: compnay_idに該当するレコードが対象です。このSQLを実行するクラス内の関数（JAVA）のパラメーターに、company_id を引数で指定します。

Comment: SQL の実行速度を高速化したいという質問であれば、テーブル定義を作成しているインデックスを含めて提示した方がよいかと思います。(できれば CREATE TABBLE 文や CREATE INDEX 文のSQLファイル添付してあると話が早いです。)

Comment: 「話が早いです」そうでしたか、大変失礼しました。抽出条件やＳＱＬ文など余計なことを書いてしまい、逆に解決できなくなっていたのですね。本当にご質問方法の的を得ておらず、申し訳ございません。混乱の元となっております、ご質問内容やSQLやレコード見本を消して、CREATE TABLE文のみにします。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: 「テーブル定義も提示」するという話であって質問内容を消したら誰も回答できないかと思いますが…

Comment: 質問文を復活させ、テーブル定義をマージしました。

Comment: 「本日以降がないデータが、抽出対象」とのことですが「6 / 2 / りんご  / 2030-12-31 / 200」が存在するため`id=5`は抽出対象外になるようにも読み取れます。どちらが正しいのでしょうか？

Comment: レコード例の間違いです。id=6のレコード例を変更しました。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Comment: 100倍の高速化、解決されて何よりです。[回答を承認](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)いただけたらと思います。

Answer (score 4):

「最大日のレコードを抽出したい」のであれば`NOT EXISTS`や`LEFT OUTER JOIN`を使うのではなく素直に集計関数`MAX`を使用することをお勧めします。「昨日以前のデータ」とのことでしたが**昨日**の定義があいまいなのでとりあえず`CURDATE()`との比較にしておきました。MySQLの動作環境でのタイムゾーンにお気を付けください。

```
SELECT food_id, MAX(buy_date)
FROM food AS f1
WHERE company_id=200 AND buy_date < CURDATE()
GROUP BY food_id
```

これで`food_id`ごとの最大の`buy_date`が得られます。これを自己結合すれば

```
SELECT f2.*
FROM (SELECT food_id, MAX(buy_date) AS max_buy_date
      FROM food
      WHERE company_id=200 AND buy_date < CURDATE()
      GROUP BY food_id) AS f1
INNER JOIN food AS f2
ON f1.food_id=f2.food_id AND f1.max_buy_date=f2.buy_date
WHERE f2.company_id=200
```

該当行が得られます。最大日のレコードが複数該当した場合について言及されていなかったので、ひとまず全て列挙されるようにしています。

---

> 本日以降がないデータが、抽出対象

これこそ`NOT EXISTS`や`LEFT OUTER JOIN`の出番ですね。とはいえ

> 昨日以前のデータで、且、最大日のデータを抽出

と組み合わせると、「最大日が本日以降となる場合は除外する」と簡単に表せます。

```
SELECT f2.*
FROM (SELECT food_id, MAX(buy_date) AS max_buy_date
      FROM food
      WHERE company_id = 200
      GROUP BY food_id) AS f1
INNER JOIN food AS f2
ON f1.food_id = f2.food_id AND f1.max_buy_date = f2.buy_date
WHERE f1.max_buy_date < CURDATE() AND f2.company_id = 200
```

でしょうか。

Comment: sayuri様、質問文章等の復旧等お手数をおかけいたしました。教えて頂いた上記のSQL文で実行してみた結果、抽出処理時間が、約20秒 ⇒ 約0.15秒へ劇的に前よりも速くなりました。ありがとうございます。但し、抽出結果のレコード数が、（今、新旧両方を何度か実行しましたが）812件⇒831件に増えていますので、抽出されたレコードを比較してみます。

Comment: @SQLで困っている難民 `buy_date`が一致する別会社まで抽出していました。除外するように条件を追加しましたのでご確認ください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。自分で気づかず申し訳ございません。試してみます。

Comment: 新SQL文の方が19レコード多く抽出される件の調査状況ですが、判明したことは、本日日付のbuy_dateがある場合も新SQL文では昨日以前の最大buy_dateが抽出対象となっていることがわかりました。本質問の条件に記述していなかったので追記し、本日以降のbuy_dateがある場合は昨日以前の最大レコードも本日以降のレコードも抽出されないように修正します。速度が速くなり、あと一歩になりました。数日間の試行錯誤もあと少しですので、何とかします。本当にありがとうございました。

Comment: ごたごたのご質問でしたが、先ほど、SQL文の変更による高速化に成功しました。
適切なご指摘やSQL文のご提示をありがとうございました。
大変お手数をお掛け致しました。（質問本文の最後の方に、最終結果SQL文などを記述しておきました）